# Floats not adding up

Tags: java, floating-point, floating-accuracy

Okay, so I'm trying to add up some very large floats, and I'm trying to do this as precisely as possible by adding the smallest ones first. However, this provides different results from what I'm supposed to be getting, and I'm not sure why. They're only off by a few points long after the decimal, so I assume it's because there's some edge case where it adds the wrong numbers.

Edit: This is different from other float issues because I am required to use floats for this project. Yes, I know that floats are bad for precision and I should be using literally anything else, but this is what I was told to do.

```
    int i = 0;
    float[] que = new float[a.length];
    //Queue<Float> que = new PriorityQueue<Float>();
    while (i < a.length){
        addarray(que, a[i], i);
        i++;
    }
    i = 0;
    while (i<que.length){
    //  System.out.println(que[i]);
        i++;
    }
    int qlength = que.length-1;
    //System.out.println("now to add");
    i = 0;
    float result = 0;
    int clength = qlength;
    while (qlength > 0){
        float x = que[0];
        que[0] = que[qlength];
        //removelast(que);
        i = 0;
        clength--;
        float[] temp = new float[que.length -1];
        while (i < que.length -1){
            temp[i] = que[i];
            i++;
        }
        i=0;
        que = new float[que.length-1];
        while (i < que.length){
            que[i] = temp[i];
            //System.out.println(que[i]);
            i++;
        }
        pulldown(que, 0);
        float y = que[0];
        que[0] = que[qlength-1];
        clength--;
        //removelast(que);
        i = 0;
        temp = new float[que.length -1];
        while (i < que.length -1){
            temp[i] = que[i];
            i++;
        }
        i=0;
        que = new float[que.length-1];
        while (i < que.length){
            que[i] = temp[i];
            //System.out.println(que[i]);
            i++;
        }
        if (que.length != 0){
        pulldown(que, 0);}
        System.out.println("adding " + x + " and " + y);
        float z = x+y;
        System.out.println("z = " + z);
        //append(que, z);
        i = 0;
        temp = new float[que.length+1];
        while (i < que.length){
            temp[i] = que[i];
            i++;
        }
        addarray(temp, z, temp.length-1);
        i=0;
        que = new float[temp.length];
        while (i < que.length){
            que[i] = temp[i];
            //System.out.println(que[i]);
            i++;
        }
        clength++;
        qlength--;
    }
    return que[0];
```

Comment: Floating point numbers are not meant to be precise; if you want precision, use `BigDecimal`.

Comment: `double` may have the same trouble. - use BigDecimal

Comment: A `float` is usually just a vague approximation to the value you want.  A `double` is a slightly better approximation.  Don't use either of those types if you value accuracy.

Comment: Yes I know that floats are terrible, but I was told to use floats so that's what I'm stuck with.